# ionic button activated / active

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am looking to set an ionic button's state to active, but this isn't documented at all in the API docs. As of right now, when you click the button, the "activated" class is added to the button, and then removed a few moments later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done via `[ngClass]="{'activated' : YourVariableHere }"`

HTML:

```
<button class="post-button" [ngClass]="{'activated' : buttonActive}"ion-button outline small icon-left">
```

Component code:

```
buttonActive: boolean = true;
```